# Cannot find module 'liferay-theme-tasks'

Tags: npm, gulp

When I try to run my GULP task it gives me an exception  `Cannot find module 'liferay-theme-tasks'`
But several days ago I deployed my project withou troubles and issues! Also I installed lifery themes. What the trouble? Any solutions?

Comment: What version of liferay-theme-tasks did you install?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and running this command line solved the problem:

```
npm install liferay-theme-tasks
```

Like in your case, I also created and deployed themes two months ago using the same computer, so I am not sure why it has disappeared, but anyway with this now it works again.